# How can I inspect the attributes of a target property using Value Injector?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, valueinjecter

I'm using Value Injector to manage my mappings in an ASP.NET MVC project and it's been great so far. The domain has the concept of a length measurement stored as standard metric units in the db and exposed as a decimal value up to the service layer.

Rendering of lengths in the UI context-specific, depending on object being measure, user culture, etc. Hints about context denoted by attributes on the properties of view model types. Using Value Injector, I want to inspect these attributes at injection time and show an appropriately formatted string to display, when the source property is a decimal and the target property is a string decorated with one of the above attributes.

```
namespace TargetValueAttributes
{
    public class Person
    {
        public decimal Height { get; set; }
        public decimal Waist { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonViewModel
    {
        [LengthLocalizationHint(LengthType.ImperialFeetAndInches)]
        [LengthLocalizationHint(LengthType.MetricMeters)]
        public string Height { get; set; }

        [LengthLocalizationHint(LengthType.ImperialInches)]
        [LengthLocalizationHint(LengthType.MetricCentimeters)]
        public string Waist { get; set; }
    }

    public enum LengthType
    {
        MetricMeters,
        MetricCentimeters,
        ImperialFeetAndInches,
        ImperialInches
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class LengthLocalizationHintAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public LengthType SuggestedLengthType { get; set; }

        public LengthLocalizationHintAttribute(LengthType suggestedLengthType)
        {
            SuggestedLengthType = suggestedLengthType;
        }
    }

    public class LengthLocalizationInjection : FlatLoopValueInjection<decimal, string>
    {
        protected override void Inject(object source, object target)
        {
            base.Inject(source, target);//I want to be able to inspect the attributes on the target value here
        }
        protected override string SetValue(decimal sourceValues)
        {
            var derivedLengthType = LengthType.MetricMeters;//here would be even better
            return sourceValues.ToLength(derivedLengthType);//this is an extension method that does the conversion to whatever the user needs to see
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around in the source, I came up with a solution based on the implementation of `FlatLoopValueInjection'.

```
public abstract class LocalizationStringInjection<TSource, TTarget> : LoopValueInjectionBase
{
    public ILocalizationContext LocalizationContext { get; set; }

    protected LocalizationStringInjection(ILocalizationContext localizationContext)
    {
        LocalizationContext = localizationContext;
    }

    protected virtual bool TypesMatch(Type sourceType, Type targetType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(TSource) && targetType == typeof(TTarget);
    }

    protected override void Inject(object source, object target)
    {
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor targetPropertyDescriptor in target.GetProps())
        {
            var t1 = targetPropertyDescriptor;
            var es = UberFlatter.Flat(targetPropertyDescriptor.Name, source, type => TypesMatch(type, t1.PropertyType));

            var endpoint = es.FirstOrDefault();
            if (endpoint == null) continue;

            var sourceValue = endpoint.Property.GetValue(endpoint.Component) is TSource ? (TSource)endpoint.Property.GetValue(endpoint.Component) : default(TSource);

            if (AllowSetValue(sourceValue))
                targetPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(target, SetValue(sourceValue, targetPropertyDescriptor));
        }
    }

    protected abstract TTarget SetValue(TSource sourcePropertyValue, PropertyDescriptor targetPropertyDescriptor);
}

public class LengthLocalizationStringInjection : LocalizationStringInjection<decimal, string>
{
    public LengthLocalizationStringInjection(ILocalizationContext localizationContext) : base(localizationContext) { }

    protected override string SetValue(decimal sourceValue, PropertyDescriptor targetPropertyDescriptor)
    {
        var lengthHints = targetPropertyDescriptor.Attributes.Cast<object>().Where(attribute => attribute.GetType() == typeof(LengthLocalizationAttribute)).Cast<LengthLocalizationAttribute>().ToList();
        return lengthHints.Any() ? sourceValue.ToLength(lengthHints.First(l => l.SuggestedLengthType == LocalizationContext.Length).SuggestedLengthType) : sourceValue.ToLength(default(LengthType));
    }
}
```

This has proven good enough for my purposes for now. I've left out some referenced types so as not to obscure the idea.